# JQuery data function returns the wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an input text which one of its `data` attribute is changed on the fly as soon as my view model changes ( thanks to Knockout).
The binding is done as follow:

```
<input data-bind="attr:{'data-customitem': customItemId}" />
```

Somewhere in my view model, I have a function which accesses the input and retrieves the `data-customitem` attribute value.

The first time the input is bound, it gets an id, say `X`. So the HTML looks like this:

```
<input data-bind="attr:{'data-customitem': customItemId}" data-customitem='X'/>
```

Then my model changes and knockout updates the attribute value to `Y`. The HTML now looks like this:

```
<input data-bind="attr:{'data-customitem': customItemId}" data-customitem='Y'/>
```

The problem now is:

`$element.data("customitem")` returns `X`

`$element.attr("data-orderitem")` returns `Y`

Why is jQuery data function returning an old value of the data attribute? Is there any caching going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a different between the jQuery's `data` function and the `attr` function.
The `data` function is binded to the element (not necessary to the `data` attribute). If an element has `data-X='val'` you can use **both** jquery's `data` function and the `attr` function to get the value:

```
$('el').data('X')
$('el').attr('data-X')
```

However - in case you change the data (using the `data(...)` function) - to get the new value you must use the `data` function (this change will not affect the value of the attribute), and the opposite is the same - if you change the value using the `attr` function - it will not affect the values of the `data()` function.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    console.log('value using data function: ' + $('#d1').data('name1'))
    console.log('value using attr function: ' + $('#d1').attr('data-name1'))
  });
  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#d1').data('name1', 'new value - using data');
  });
  $('#btn3').click(function() {
    $('#d1').attr('data-name1', 'new value - using attr');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1" data-name1="abc"></div>
<button id="btn1">Get Values</button><br />
<button id="btn2">Change Values using data function</button><br />
<button id="btn3">Change Values using attr function</button><br />
```

The changes you are doing (using `data-bing="attr:{...}"`) don't affect the values of the jQuery's `data` function.

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot for the great explanation. I thought the data function is just some sort of alias for the attr function and that the underlying data is the same. I was completely wrong :) +1 and accepted answer.